# Transforming a gzip file into npy file

Tags: python, numpy

For my my ML model I need to open a gzip file and convert it to an array.
My code looks like this:

```
def load_data(path):
    with np.load(path) as f:
        x_train, y_train = f['x_train'], f['y_train']
        x_test, y_test = f['x_test'], f['y_test']
        return (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test)

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = load_data('../input/mnist-numpy/mnist.npz')

x_train = trainimages.reshape(trainimages.shape[0],784)
y_train = trainimages.reshape(trainimages.shape[0],1)
x_test = testimages.reshape(testimages.shape[0],784)
y_test = testimages.reshape(testimages.shape[0],1)
MNIST_image = np.vstack( (x_train,x_test) )
MNIST_label = np.vstack( (y_train,y_test) )
```

At the moment I'm getting an error because I can't reshape the GZ file.
Does anyone know how to create arrays or maybe there's another solution to run the code?

My error looks like this

```
 Traceback (most recent call last): File "<ipython-input-18-c86c75005844>", line 1, in <module> 
    x_train = trainimages.reshape(trainimages.shape[0],784) 
 AttributeError: 'GzipFile' object has no attribute 'reshape'
```

Comment: ```
x_train = trainimages.reshape(trainimages.shape[0],784)
y_train = trainimages.reshape(trainimages.shape[0],1)
x_test = testimages.reshape(testimages.shape[0],784)
y_test = testimages.reshape(testimages.shape[0],1)
MNIST_image = np.vstack( (x_train,x_test) )
MNIST_label = np.vstack( (y_train,y_test) )
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-18-c86c75005844>", line 1, in <module>
    x_train = trainimages.reshape(trainimages.shape[0],784)

AttributeError: 'GzipFile' object has no attribute 'reshape'
```

Comment: important information always put in question, not in comment. It will be more readable.

Comment: As already suggested, please *do not* post such info in the comments - edit & update your post insytead

Comment: The file tag is `npz`.  Is this a zip archive produced by `savez`, or a file that has been compressed with gzip?

Comment: What is `trainimages`? The `load_data` call doesn't set that.  Why aren't''t you reshaping `x_train`?

Answer (score 0):

This code and error is not about loading a `gzip` file.

Evidently `trainimages` is a `GzipFile` object, but that's not what the `load_data` function produces.  It must be left over from some earlier coding in the script.

Evidently `load_data` operates successfully on the `npz` file, which is a `zip-archive` (possibly with its own non-gzip compression).  It returns 4 arrays, with names like `x_train`, etc.  It's those arrays that may need reshaping (I'd check first), not the spurious `trainimages`.